# Convert date range to array of weeks and months

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to take a given date range and convert it to an array of dates that are the end of calendar weeks and months.

So, same range, but would have a `weeks` and `months` output.

Range: `Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")`

Output:

```
weeks = ["2014-02-02", "2014-02-09", "2014-02-16", "2014-02-23", "2014-03-02", "2014-03-09", "2014-03-16", "2014-03-23", "2014-03-02", "2014-03-30"]
months = ["2014-01-31", "2014-02-28", "2014-03-31"]
```

I happen to be doing this inside a Rails app, so the Rails helper methods are available here (for example, [end_of_week](http://apidock.com/rails/DateAndTime/Calculations/end_of_week)).

Comment: what is the logic of finding weeks ?

Comment: your range ends at 03/27 but months include 03/31 as well?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can think of as below :

```
require 'date'

months = (Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).group_by(&:month).map { |_,v| v.first.end_of_month.to_s } 
# => ["2014-01-31", "2014-02-28", "2014-03-31"]

weeks = (Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).select(&:sunday?).map(&:to_s) 
# => ["2014-02-02",
#     "2014-02-09",
#     "2014-02-16",
#     "2014-02-23",
#     "2014-03-02",
#     "2014-03-09",
#     "2014-03-16",
#     "2014-03-23"]
```

Comment: I think I need to learn many Array shortcuts from your answers!

Comment: And I think that your output does not match the expected output. :)

Comment: You need `(Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27").end_of_month)` range to get the exact output. But it might not work in all conditions. May be you can find a better alternative.

Comment: Weeks also has the end of month listed.

Comment: I guess so. +1 for an awesome answer.

Comment: @ArupRakshit your answer is good but it is missing on months if date range covers more than 12 months.

Comment: Perfect answer. I tried `cweek`, it does well. `(start_date..end_date).group_by(&:cweek).map{|week| week[1].first }`. Includes weeks less than 7 days and first and last dates of week.

Answer (score 1):

For week use step.

```
(Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).step(7).map(&:to_s)
```

For month it will not work, because number of days varies.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.sunday?` to find out it is a weekend and `end_of_month` to find out if it is a month end.

Weekends:

```
(Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).each { |d| puts d if d.sunday?}
```

Month ends:

```
(Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).each { |d| puts d if d == d.end_of_month}
```

Answer (score 0):

*This answer is considering all months in date range even if date range covers more than 12 months.*

```
d1 = Date.parse("2014-01-30") 
d2 = Date.parse("2014-03-27")
```

For using Ruby:--

```
months = ((d1)..(d2)).each_with_object([]){|d, o| o << (Date.civil(d.year, d.month, -1)).to_s}.uniq

sundays = ((d1)..(d2.wday < 7 ? d2 + 7 - d2.wday : d2)).each_with_object([]){|d, o| o << d.to_s if d.sunday?}
```

For using Rails:--

```
months = ((d1)..(d2.end_of_month)).each_with_object([]){|d, o| o << d.to_s if d.sunday?}

sundays = ((d1)..(d2.end_of_month)).each_with_object([]){|d, o| o << d.end_of_month.to_s}.uniq
```

*While getting array of month's end date, my logic of finding end date of each month is not efficient. But, my logic of finding array of Sundays' date is better.*

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with plain Ruby (no ActiveSupport or Rails):

```
weeks = (Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).select(&:sunday?)
months = (Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).select { |x| (x + 1).month != x.month }
```

With Rails:

```
weeks = (Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).select(&:sunday?)
months = (Date.parse("2014-01-30")..Date.parse("2014-03-27")).map(&:end_of_month).uniq
```

Comment: your answer misses end of calender week and month, and your answer is collections of date object.